# autocomplete="off" is not working

Tags: html

I have a textfield that always show its history (what people have typed there). I googling about it and find out that i can use `autocomplete="off"`. So i tried this code, which is inside a `div` tag :

```
<p><input type="text" name="txt_nama" id="txt_nama" autocomplete="off" /></p>
```

But the annoying history is still showing. What should i do?

This is the SS that may help you :

[image]

Thanks :D

Comment: What browser are you using? Just because it [works absolutely fine](http://jsfiddle.net/8hyw9/) for me...

Comment: @bažmegakapa i use chrome :D

Comment: What is the doctype of your page? Is this issue now resolved? This attribute will only work with the HTML5 doctype (http://diveintohtml5.info/introduction.html#three) or as non-standard in Internet Explorer with legacy doctypes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autocomplete for more on the autocomplete attribute.

Comment: @pwdst sad to be said, i still cant resolve it until now...and it seems smthng was wrong, my question got downvoted @@ I use <!doctype html>

Comment: Is this on a public page you can provide a URL to so we can have a look?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `autocomplete` was introduced by Internet Explorer and it's not a standard feature if you don't use HTML5 (XHTML or HTML4). Also `autocomplete="off"` prevents the browser from saving the values, **it doesn't prevent fields** getting populated with values saved from another another site that it's not using autocomplete on its fields.

Comment: It might have been introduced by IE, but in HTML5 it's standard.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) i didn't know it.

Comment: @Patrick It's not standard, it's merely suggested to become standard at this point, because there is no HTML5 standard yet :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. How to remove the "history" like the picture i put in my question?

Comment: @hvd Oke, you are right. It's not official yet, but I don't think it's going to change either:)

Comment: Because it doesn't avoid populating fields from other inputs, the autocomplete window will still apear even if he is using autocomplete=off

Comment: @hvd The W3C version of HTML5.0 is now Candidate Recommendation, which means that all theoretical issues of the spec are resolved and it is completely ready for implementation. For example, the CSS2.1 spec had the same status until June 2011. The WHATWG version of the spec is called 'The Living Standard', which means that the spec is always evolving but considered complete at any moment. They both have `autocomplete` attribute.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn About the W3C version: sure, but that does not contradict what I have said. Good point about the WHATWG version though, I didn't know that.

Comment: Sorry for the long response, i left this project for a while. So if autocomplete is not working, what should i do to get rid of those history? Thanks :D

Comment: Clean your browser history :( this option depends on client no on  the website.